# Play video with subtitles in JavaFX 2

Tags: video, javafx-2, javafx, subtitle

I notice that JavaFX 1 has a `SubtitleTrack` class for extracting subtitles from video files, but I can't find equivalent functionality in JavaFX 2 (a similarly named class in `javafx.scene.media` doesn't appear to exist. Is this functionality implemented at all in which case where has it moved to? Or is it planned for a future release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think video subtitle support was implemented for JavaFX 2.2.

I think the [Public API changes to media Tracks](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-25678) feature implements the functionality you ask about.  You can test out the implementation in the latest [jdk8 snapshot release](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html).