# Play video with subtitles in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, video, subtitle

Is it possible to play a video in JavaFX with .srt subtitles included? I mean to actually get the subtitle track and display it as ordinary text in the GUI, not hard coded into the video.

Comment: what's your problem exactly? Nothing available out-of-the-box, but shouldn't be too hare: read the srt (it contains the stop/end times, right?), then play the video and add them on a transparent label during those times

Comment: @kleopatra There's no problem, I'm just asking if it's possible since I'm considering whether to learn and use JavaFX or not.

Answer (score -2):

I think you will found your answer by this way : be carefull this feature is only available in jfx 2 or greater

[Play video with subtitles in JavaFX 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197243/play-video-with-subtitles-in-javafx-2)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: That question is 7 years old and the current version of JavaFX is 11. I already saw that question but was posting since I thought there must be different/better/other information by now. Also the link in the answer to that question is broken.